# Setting state along with debounce

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a textInput with a simple autocomplete functionality. It works by sending a fetch request, and then the server returns the values that are stored in an array. Fetch request is sent on a debounce when the user types something in the input, using onChange. I also need the input's value to be stored in state variable inputValue, but this cannot be debounced, in case the user writes fast. Is there a way to somehow attach both of these in onChange? Here is my code and not working attempt:

```
const TextInput = () => {
    const [autoCompleteVal, setAutoCompleteVal] = useState([])
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()

    const inputDebounce = (func, timeout = 300) => {
        let timer;
        return (...args) => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(() => {func.apply(this, args)}, timeout)
        }
    }
    const fetchData = (e) => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000', {
            filterBy: e.target.value,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setAutoCompleteVal(response.data)
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    const handleChange = inputDebounce((e) => fetchData(e))

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.innerText)
        setAutoCompleteVal([])
    }

      let listItems = autoCompleteVal.map(word =>
      <div key={word} onClick={handleClick}>{word}</div>
      )


    return(
        <div>
            <div id="textInputContainer">
                <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} id="textInput" type='text' />
                {autoCompleteVal.length !== 0 && <div className="suggestions">{listItems}</div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TextInput;
```

Tried to combine it like this

```
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setAutoCompleteVal(e.target.value)
        inputDebounce((e) => fetchData(e))(e)
    }
```

but it feels incredibly wrong and is not working.

Huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever finds this helpful, i just changed the input state variable into a ref, and then changed my debounce function to this.
Will close this question tomorrow, as soon as the website will allow me to do so.

```
    const inputDebounce = (func, timeout = 300) => {
        let timer;
        return (...args) => {
            inputValueRef.current = args[0].target.value
            clearTimeout(timer)
            timer = setTimeout(() => {func.apply(this, args)}, timeout)
        }
    }
```